# Measuring and exporting merge sort algorithm execution time into CSV?

Tags: java, algorithm, csv, sorting, mergesort

My task is to implement the merge-sort algorithm on an array G of large length L (with random values hitting a max value).

The pseudocode is as follows:

```
DataCollect () 
 for n = 1,000 to L (step 1,000) 
   Copy in array A n first values from array G.
   Take current time : Start (timing the sort of array A of length n)
   Merge-Sort (A, 0, n-1) 
   Take current time: End. Or T(n) = End - Start
   Store value n and values...(various time complexities) in file F. T(n) is execution time.
```

This is what I came up with...but I cannot seem to figure out my error. I feel like I sorted it correctly, but the data that results from this program just does not sit right with me. Is there an error in my logic here or am I just over thinking this?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main { 

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
  System.out.println(collectData());           
        
 }   

 public static long collectData() throws IOException { 
  
  int L = 10000; 
  long start = 0;
  long end = 0;
  long Tn = 0; 
  
  int G[] = RData(L); 
  int A[]; 
  
  File file= new File("collectData.csv");
  FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file);
  
  filewriter.append("T(n)");
  filewriter.append(',');
  filewriter.append('n');
  filewriter.append(',');
  filewriter.append("T(n)/n");
  filewriter.append(',');
  filewriter.append("T(n)/nlog(n)");
  filewriter.append(',');
  filewriter.append("T(n)/nsqrt(n)");
  filewriter.append("\n");
  
  for (int n = 1000; n <= G.length; n += 1000) { 
     A = copyVal(G, n); 
        
     start = System.currentTimeMillis();
     mergeSort(A, 0, A.length - 1);
     end = System.currentTimeMillis();
     Tn = end - start;
     
     filewriter.write(String.valueOf(Tn));
     filewriter.append(',');
     filewriter.write(String.valueOf(n));
     filewriter.append(',');
     filewriter.write(String.valueOf(Tn/(n)));
     filewriter.append(',');
     filewriter.write(String.valueOf(Tn/(n * Math.log(n))));
     filewriter.append(',');
     filewriter.write(String.valueOf(Tn/(n * (Math.sqrt(n)))));
     filewriter.append(',');
     filewriter.write("\n");
     
  }  
  filewriter.flush();
  filewriter.close();
  return Tn;

  }

  public static void mergeSort(int[] Array, int p, int r) {

  if(p < r) {
    
     int q = (p + r)/2;
    
     mergeSort(Array, p, q);
     mergeSort(Array, q + 1, r);
     merge(Array, p, q, r);
  }

 }

  private static void merge(int[] Array, int p, int q, int r) {
 // finds the sizes of the two arrays to merge
  int n1 = q - p + 1;
  int n2 = r - q;
  
 // temporary arrays created
  int L[] = new int[n1 + 1];
  int R[] = new int[n2 + 1];
  
 // copying the data to the temp arrays
  for(int i = 1; i < n1; i++) {
     L[i] = Array[p + i - 1];
  }
  for(int j = 1; j < n2; j++) {
     R[j] = Array[q + j];
  }
 // replace the infinity with 0x0fff ffff value
  L[n1] = 268435455;
  R[n2] = 268435455;
  
 // initial values
  int i = 0, j = 0; 

  for(int k = p; k <= r; k++) {
     if(L[i] <= R[j]) {
        Array[k] = L[i];
        i = i + 1;
     }
     else {
        Array[k] = R[j];
        j = j + 1;
     }
  }


 }
 // copies A 
 public static int[] copyVal(int[] G, int n) {

  int[] A = new int[n];

  for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
     A[i] = G[i];
  }

  return A;
 }


 public static int[] RData(int n) {
  int[] Array = new int[n + 1];

  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     Array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE);
  }

  return Array;
  
 }

 }
```

Comment: Have you test just the merge sort?  Make sure it works before doing anything else with it.

Comment: Please explain why you think there is an error

Comment: I tested the merge sort on a separate set of values- it definitely works. When I run the program, I feel like the values I obtain in the export don't make sense...when I graph the time complexities I am calculating the (n) value is much larger than the (Tn/(n * (Math.sqrt(n)) value- wouldn't these be at a similar level?